# Bash function, array howto?

Tags: arrays, bash, function

I'm struggling to wrap my head around Bash arrays, in particular I have this function where I need to load an array; What I have written is this:

`function list_files() {
    for f in *; do
        [[ -e $f ]] || continue
    done
}`

```
function list_array() {

    array=list_files
    number=0

    for items in "${array[@]}"
    do
            let "number +=1"
            echo -e "\033[1m$number\033[0m) $items"
            tput sgr0
            let "number -=$(echo "${#array[*]}")"
    done
}
```

The problem here is that the function only works once, however I need to run this several times in the script. I am unsure how to go about doing this. Either I have to empty and reload the array every time the function is invoked, or I have to supply a different array name in the function parameter (list_array myarrayname in stead of just list_array). However I have no idea how to accomplish either of these tasks, or if they are possible/feasible.

Any help would be very welcomed!

Comment: "the function only works once"?! It does not work at all. There are syntax errors in your code.

Comment: [never parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) use file-globbing instead

Comment: What do you think `if $array` does?

Answer (score 0):

A bit unclear what you are trying to achieve; perhaps you can find some inspiration from below:

```
#!/bin/bash

list_files() {
    number=0
    for f in *
    do
        if [[ -f $f ]]
        then
            number=$((number+=1))
            echo $f, $number
        fi
    done
}

list_files_array() {
    array=($1/*)
    number=0
    for item in ${array[@]}
    do
        if [[ -f $item ]]
        then
            number=$((number+=1))
            echo $item, $number
        fi
    done
}

list_files $(pwd)
list_files_array $(pwd)
```